# R shiny code to generate excel tabs by click

Tags: r, excel, shiny, reactive

I am trying to create a new excel workbook, with new tabs (loaded with data) by a click. For example, when the user clicks on "Save this View", the code should generate an excel (at first instance), add tab and copy the table. On next click, the code should add tab to existing excel and copy the data.

```
library(writexl)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(openxlsx)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(rlist)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    fluidRow(    column(  width = 10,
                          tags$h3("Select Filters"),
                          panel(  selectizeGroupUI(
                            id = "my-filters1",
                            inline = F,
                            params = list(
                              cyl = list(inputId = "cyl", title = "cyl",multiple=TRUE),
                              gear = list(inputId = "gear", title = "gear",multiple=TRUE),
                              carb = list(inputId = "carb", title = "carb",multiple=TRUE)
                            )
                          ), status = "primary"))),
    actionButton("add1","Save This Veiw"),textAreaInput("caption", "Sheetname", "Output", width = "150px",height=40),
    pickerInput("filter", "Select",multiple = TRUE,options = list(
      `actions-box` = TRUE),c("gear","carb","gear"),selected = c("gear"))



  ),
  mainPanel(
    downloadButton("dl", "Download"),
  dataTableOutput("data1")
)

)
server <- function(input, output) {

  res_mod1 <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters1",
    data = mtcars,
    vars = c("cyl","gear","carb")

  )


  base_data <- reactive({ 
    res<- mtcars

    #res$Settlement.Amount.GBP<-ifelse(is.na(res$Settlement.Amount),0,res$Settlement.Amount) 
    if (!(is.null(input$`my-filters1-cyl`))) res<-filter(res, (cyl) == input$`my-filters1-cyl`)
    if (!(is.null(input$`my-filters1-gear`))) res<-filter(res, (gear) == input$`my-filters1-gear`)
    if (!(is.null(input$`my-filters1-carb`))) res<-filter(res, (carb) == input$`my-filters1-carb`)

    res2<- res%>% select(input$filter,mpg)%>%
      group_by(!!!rlang::syms(input$filter)) %>% 
      summarise_at(vars(mpg),funs(sum))


    res2
  }) 




  output$data1 <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(base_data()))



   filename = function() {
          "output_file.xlsx"
       }
   content = function(file) {
         my_workbook <- createWorkbook()}





   x<-reactive({ observeEvent(input$add1, {
     addWorksheet(
              wb = my_workbook,
             sheetName = input$caption
           )
     writeData(
              my_workbook,
             sheet = 1,
             base_data1(),
             startRow = 6,
             startCol = 2
          )

   })})
   # 
  # 
  # 
  # 
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

    filename,
   content,x
  #     
  #   }
  #   
 )

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks,

Comment: the `my_workbook` object is created once you click the download button therefore it won't work with an `observeEvent`. You might be better off creating the openxlsx object in your global file and the simply add an `observeEvent` that adds to that. See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my previous comment:

```
library(writexl)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(openxlsx)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(rlist)

my_workbook <- createWorkbook()

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    fluidRow(    column(  width = 10,
                          tags$h3("Select Filters"),
                          panel(  selectizeGroupUI(
                            id = "my-filters1",
                            inline = F,
                            params = list(
                              cyl = list(inputId = "cyl", title = "cyl",multiple=TRUE),
                              gear = list(inputId = "gear", title = "gear",multiple=TRUE),
                              carb = list(inputId = "carb", title = "carb",multiple=TRUE)
                            )
                          ), status = "primary"))),
    actionButton("add1","Save This Veiw"),textAreaInput("caption", "Sheetname", "Output", width = "150px",height=40),
    pickerInput("filter", "Select",multiple = TRUE,options = list(
      `actions-box` = TRUE),c("gear","carb","gear"),selected = c("gear"))



  ),
  mainPanel(
    downloadButton("dl", "Download"),
    dataTableOutput("data1")
  )

)
server <- function(input, output) {

  res_mod1 <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters1",
    data = mtcars,
    vars = c("cyl","gear","carb")

  )


  base_data <- reactive({ 
    res<- mtcars

    #res$Settlement.Amount.GBP<-ifelse(is.na(res$Settlement.Amount),0,res$Settlement.Amount) 
    if (!(is.null(input$`my-filters1-cyl`))) res<-filter(res, (cyl) == input$`my-filters1-cyl`)
    if (!(is.null(input$`my-filters1-gear`))) res<-filter(res, (gear) == input$`my-filters1-gear`)
    if (!(is.null(input$`my-filters1-carb`))) res<-filter(res, (carb) == input$`my-filters1-carb`)

    res2<- res%>% select(input$filter,mpg)%>%
      group_by(!!!rlang::syms(input$filter)) %>% 
      summarise_at(vars(mpg),funs(sum))


    res2
  }) 




  output$data1 <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(base_data()))



  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("output_file",".xlsx", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      saveWorkbook(my_workbook, file, overwrite = TRUE)
    }
  )




observeEvent(input$add1, {
    addWorksheet(
      wb = my_workbook,
      sheetName = input$caption
    )
    writeData(
      my_workbook,
      sheet = 1,
      base_data(),
      startRow = 6,
      startCol = 2
    )

  })


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This should do the trick. You need to call the `observeEvent` to add the table to the global workbook placeholder once the user clicks on "Save this view". After that, you simply `saveWorkbook` once the user clicks the download button.

Comment: Thanks Maylo, this overwrite each time I click on save. I want to create new tab for each click and save in the same excel. I tried ```writeData(
      my_workbook,
      sheetname = input$caption,
      base_data(),
      startRow = 6,
      startCol = 2
    ) ```

Comment: The app will automatically add a tab each time you click save as long as the Sheet name does not already exist. If you try using saving two sheets with the same name, the one will overwrite the other. I guess you could do something in lines of `if (input$caption %in% sheets(my_workbook))` and warn the user that this sheet already exists

Comment: You are genius my friend.. the code worked beautifully. Only change I did was ```writeData(
      my_workbook,
      sheet = 1,
      base_data(),
      startRow = 6,
      startCol = 2
    )``` changed this to ```writeData(
      my_workbook,
      sheet = input$caption,
      base_data(),
      startRow = 6,
      startCol = 2
    )```